# Navbar font doesn't increase on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar, font-size

I'm trying to make my navbar text (which are links) increase font-size on mouseover. Sadly I can't make it work. Could it be that display: inline(-block) makes it impossible? Or could it be because I didn't specify a font-size in the CSS for my navbar? My text is white on black background and the font-size is (I think) inherited from body.

Here is what I have tried:

```
.size-increase:hover {
font-size: 200%
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1.5)
}
```

While this works well for my button, it doesn't do anything to my navbar. I then tried to make a separate CSS hover for my navbar only and have tried all the below font-increase methods individually.

```
  .navbar-links:hover{
 font-size: 5px;
font-size: larger;
font-size: 150%

}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar-transparent">
  <div class="container"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/images/logo/logo-light.png" alt="Logo" class="logo"/></a><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#side-menu" class="toggle-menu menu-right pull-right push-body nav-icon"><span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center">
      <ul class="navbar-nav-transparent text-center">
        <li><a href="#about" class="size-increase navbar-links">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#video-intro" class="size-increase navbar-links">VIDEO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services" class="size-increase navbar-links">REQUIREMENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works" class="size-increase navbar-links">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#team" class="size-increase navbar-links">INTERVIEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="size-increase navbar-links">APPLY</a></li>
      </ul>
```

And here is CSS:

```
.navbar ul.navbar-nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  list-style: none;
  width: 97%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul.navbar-nav > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not properly written; you have `class=size-increase navbar-links`

instead of

`class="size-increase navbar-links"`

```
navbar-links:hover{}
```

Should be

```
.navbar-links:hover{}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed it, but increasing the size still doesn't work.

Comment: .navbar-links:hover{}

Comment: Thanks, also edited that, but still doesn't work. (I'm checking with both individually btw, "navbar-links" and "size-increase")

Comment: The code you posted is not complete and this way people cannot help you.

Comment: @DanielaB67 What do you mean with incomplete? I posted everything in my code which includes the mentioned navbar/hover. What part am I missing?

Comment: @Cassidy - the divs and nav tag were not closed. After checking your code in Codepen, I do not understand what is not increasing on rollover. Please check your code here: https://codepen.io/DannaB67/pen/vZZKvJ